# Can't buy Battlefield 3 Premium Edition via Origin (Promo code error)

Tags: battlefield-3

I'm having trouble. I tried buying Battlefield 3 Premium Edition on Origin (On PC) and it didn't work. It says: This promo code does not apply to the items in your cart. More info. I don't have any promo code there, and it's blank. How do I fix this so I can buy it? Thanks!

[image: image of issue]

I'm trying to contact EA but I'm going to have to wait like 50-55 for an advisor. So I'd prefer if you please give me the answer in this post. Thanks!

Comment: I can't even see the error. The picture is too pixelated.

Answer (score 0):

Just have them call you, go to the Origin/EA site and report your issue. Say problem not solved and select the option to have them call you, just have to put in your number, I've done it before for BF4 issues.